# PHP: Destroying SESSIONS

Tags: php, forms, session

I am using php for server side. How do you destroy one session without destroying another session. Let me explain. I created a form where instead of using regular variables I'm using session variables. When the form is submitted I was using a session_destroy() at the end of the post so to clear the page but it also logs me out destroying the log in session. How could I just destroy the forms session variables without destroying the log in session. Sorry for being real noobish.

Answer (score 2):

to avoid many session unset() you may use like this.

```
<?php
$_session["form_values"]["data1"]=form data1;
$_session["form_values"]["data2"]=form data2;
$_session["form_values"]["data2"]=form data3;
?>
```

after saved the value, just unset like this.

```
<?php
unset($_session["form_values"]);
?>
```

Hope this saves you.

Answer (score 1):

`session_destroy()`  destroys all of the data associated with the current session.

What you need is [**unset**](https://www.php.net/unset) to clear any specific session with specifying it's key like:

`unset($_SESSION['your_vars']);`

[Reference](https://www.php.net/session_destroy).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove session variables like any other PHP variable:

```
unset($_SESSION['whatever']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `session_destroy()` will remove the session completely.

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables
>   again, session_start() has to be called.
>
> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the
>   session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the
>   session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be
>   deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

use `unset($_SESSION['session_var']);`

> unset() destroys the specified variables.
>
> The behavior of unset() inside of a function can vary depending on
>   what type of variable you are attempting to destroy.
>
> If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function, only the
>   local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment
>   will retain the same value as before unset() was called.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
unset($_SESSION['var']);

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use unset to clear a specific session

```
unset($_SESSION['session name here']);
```